# Permananet Redirect

Tags: web-server, redirect, google-webmaster-tools

I have a domain, say www.example.com which is redirected to a website built in Google Sites. I don't want different search engines treat example.com as a different site from www.example.com. How do I make a permanent link between the two? My domain is under GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [canonical tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) pointing to your preferred site.  Crawlers that obey canonical links will not treat example.com as unique from www.example.com.  Format of the link looks something like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page.html" />
```

The link above will take you to the google webmaster blog entry for a better explanation that I'm providing :)